# How to select a table column by column header name using XPath

Tags: xpath

How can I select a table column by column header name with XPath?

My attempt is:

`//table/tbody/tr/td[count(//table/thead/tr/th[.="$columnName"]/preceding-sibling::th)+1]`

This is not working.

It always selects the first column no matter what value I provide for `$columnName`.

Answer (score 0):

There is barely any information in this post, but my educated guess would be that

```
count(//table/thead/tr/th[.="$columnName"]/preceding-sibling::th)+1
```

is always equal to `1` because you use `$columnName` in *quotes* - which makes it a string, not a variable.

If this is indeed the problem, using

```
count(//table/thead/tr/th[.=$columnName]/preceding-sibling::th)+1
```

would solve it. If it doesn't, you really need to give more information - show the whole input document, indicate the programming language, show all of that code.

Comment: My actual string is as follows:  //table/tbody/tr[contains(@class,'dhx_skyblue')]/td[count(//table/thead/tr/th[.='columnName']/preceding-sibling::th)+1]

Comment: @user936636 Er, then why did you insert `$` in your question? Simply give _all_ relevant information (your program code, the input document).